# LibreOffice Calc macro to copy a range from one sheet to a different location in a different sheet

Tags: macros, libreoffice, calc

Using a macro, I want to copy whatever contents are in Sheet1,B2:D5 into Sheet2,A1 as a 'header cell'. There are numerous 'flirting around the edge' pages in the web on this but I can't uncover anything specific and I'm not able to adapt their code what I want to do, which is hugely disappointing as I had hoped to be be able to 'self generate' code in LO basic by now but apparently not :(
Would someone be so kind as to post a simple macro as to how to do this?

Edit: Here's where I am...

```
Sub try6

    Dim oSourceSheet as Object
    Dim oTargetSheet as Object
    Dim SourceRange As New com.sun.star.table.CellRangeAddress ' SourceRange with later Sheet1 like properties of what to copy '
    Dim TargetRange As New com.sun.star.table.CellAddress  ' TargetRange with later Sheet2 like properties of what to copy '

    oSourceSheet = ThisComponent.Sheets.getByName("Sheet1")
    oTargetSheet = ThisComponent.Sheets.getByName("Sheet2")   
    oSourceRange = oSourceSheet.getCellRangeByName("B2:D3") ' Specify the range to copy
    oTargetRange = oTargetSheet.getCellRangeByName("A1") ' Specify the header cell for pasting

    oTargetSheet.copyRange(TargetRange, SourceRange) ' Now nothing at all happens when the macro triggering button is pressed
    
End Sub
```

P.S. I can do it using loops, but as a 'paste block range' is where I fall down but that's how I want to do it.

Comment: Why do you need a macro, if you could use direct references or functions?

Comment: Please add new information by [edit]ing your question, do not post comments. While you're at it, please add your attempt, and tell us why it does not satisfy you, please.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I've written the code as I currently have it,
It's based on what I've seen elsewhere for slightly similar requirements.

I want macro code as those blocks of cells are going to be replaced various times with various data. I already learned how to test for data type so I'm not featuring that here.

Comment: Just as an example what I mean: Let's say Sheet1!B2 holds 23, than having Sheet2!A1 the formula `=Sheet1!B2` will make that cell's value be equal to 23, too. It follows the source cell's value all the time. You can change Sheet1!B2 and Sheet2!A1 follows immediately. Why and when do you call the macro, that it makes a difference? -- Are you aware of the multiple functions that index cells, build references, or dereference them again? And the option of matrix formulas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Sub Copy_a_Range
    'The following example copies the B2:C3 range on Sheet1 to the range starts at position A6 on Sheet2
    'Reference:  https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/BASIC_Guide#Inserting_and_Deleting_Rows_and_Columns  
    Dim Doc As Object
    Dim Sheet As Object
    Dim Target_Sheet As Object
    Dim CellRangeAddress As New com.sun.star.table.CellRangeAddress
    Dim CellAddress As New com.sun.star.table.CellAddress
    
    Doc = ThisComponent
    Sheet = Doc.Sheets(0)
    Target_Sheet = Doc.Sheets(1)
    
    ' SOURCE:
    CellRangeAddress.Sheet = 0
    CellRangeAddress.StartColumn = 1
    CellRangeAddress.StartRow = 1
    CellRangeAddress.EndColumn = 2
    CellRangeAddress.EndRow = 2
    
    ' TARGET:
    CellAddress.Sheet = 1
    CellAddress.Column = 0
    CellAddress.Row = 5
    
    Target_Sheet.copyRange(CellAddress, CellRangeAddress)
    End Sub


' ------------------
' OR...
'I've since come across this useful page in
' dealing with ranges:
' wiki.documentfoundation.org/Macros/Basic/Calc/Ranges –

Sub New_Copy_Range
sheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
    source = sheet.getCellRangeByName("B1:F3")
    target = sheet.getCellRangeByName("c16")
    sheet.copyRange(target.CellAddress, source.RangeAddress)
End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can record a macro in LibreOffice, but it's limited

[image]

using this function, LibreOffice created, with some smal changes in the format:

```
REM  *****  BASIC  *****

sub try1
    rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    rem define variables
    dim document   as object
    dim dispatcher as object
    rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    rem get access to the document
    document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
    dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

    rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    dim args2(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    args2(0).Name = "ToPoint"
    args2(0).Value = "$B$2:$D$5"

    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:GoToCell", "", 0, args2())

    rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:Copy", "", 0, Array())

    rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    dim args4(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    args4(0).Name = "Nr"
    args4(0).Value = 2

    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:JumpToTable", "", 0, args4())

    rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    dim args5(5) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    args5(0).Name = "Flags"
    args5(0).Value = "SVD"
    args5(1).Name = "FormulaCommand"
    args5(1).Value = 0
    args5(2).Name = "SkipEmptyCells"
    args5(2).Value = false
    args5(3).Name = "Transpose"
    args5(3).Value = false
    args5(4).Name = "AsLink"
    args5(4).Value = false
    args5(5).Name = "MoveMode"
    args5(5).Value = 4

    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:InsertContents", "", 0, args5())

end sub
```

EDIT:  Recordsing a Mavro in Excel2013 produces:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

    Range("B2:D5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

But this will not work in LibreOffice Calc

Comment: Your assistance is highly appreciated, thanks, but sadly I already had this method achieved - I suspected that somehow the macro-recorder  method was causing a bug later on in my program when other macros were used. the data the macro recorder was writing later inexplicably jumping up into empty cells, so I wanted a hand-coded / 'hard coded' / manual-coded macro instead using range manipulation.

Comment: "the data the macro recorder was inexplicably jumping up into empty cells..." No, it simply recorded the clicks you have done (which you, obviously, did not want to record!)

Comment: I understand the macro recorder reads clicks etc, and when I ran my the macro recorder code, it worked. But upon running a subsequent independent macro that had nothing to do with the cells the marco recorder  wrote into (of which several blanks were included) then the macro recorder data jumped up to fill the empty cells it had previously written. It was impossible to understand why, so I'm trying to use a Range 'block' method. How to achieve it?

Comment: I was 'raised' on VBA and Excel and I found it a quite intuitive, however I made the decision to move to Open Source software and hence I want to be fairly competent in LibreOffice (which i have massive respect for), but I'm finding it a tad more esoteric, and just dabbling in code as a side interest, I need help a fair number of times. I would have thought copying and pasting a Range in the manner I'm looking for would be well established already, but www searches (or at least my www searches) don't hit the mark

Comment: I was able to get the function `NonEmptyCellsInRange(oRange, sep$)` (see: https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/is-it-possible-to-write-basic-macros-for-libre-office-calc-in-windows-that-access-the-cell-and-range-objects/46325) working. It uses CellRanges too, so it might be of help...

Comment: And, you are right, Creating macro's using VBA is easier than doing this in LibreOffice.

Comment: I've since come across this useful page in dealing with ranges:
wiki.documentfoundation.org/Macros/Basic/Calc/Ranges –

sub New_Copy_Range

sheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet

    source = sheet.getCellRangeByName("B1:F3")

    target = sheet.getCellRangeByName("c16")

    sheet.copyRange(target.CellAddress, source.RangeAddress)

end sub